How to print current page's left and right headers on this page?
I want to print the current page's left and right headers on this page. I used \leftmark and \rightmark, but when I used \lhead{} and \rhead{} to assign the header before, the output of \leftmark and \rightmark remained unchanged. How can I solve this?

The following is the MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\lhead{leftheader}
\rhead{rightheader}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{SEC1}
\subsection{SUB1}

\clearpage

\leftmark, \rightmark

\end{document}


Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

\lhead{} and \rhead{} do not set the contents of \leftmark or \rightmark. commands like \section set \leftmark, \rightmark etc.

@cabohah The MWE is added.

never use marks within the body of the document, they are set up in the output routine, that is why the system exists at all, the values are not generally known  in the document (\clearpage might make some cases work but still conceptually it is wrong)

If you want \leftmark and \rightmark in the page header you have to use it as argument, e.g., of \lhead and \rhead:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{SEC1}
\subsection{SUB1}

\clearpage

Test

\end{document}

But note, that \sectionmark usually also cleans the right mark and \rightmark is the first right mark of the page. So on the section page it is still empty:

scrlayer-scrpage has a \rightbotmark for such cases:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automark,autooneside=false,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightbotmark}

\begin{document}

\section{SEC1}
\subsection{SUB1}

\clearpage

Test

\end{document}


I don't know, whether fancyhdr provides a similar command.
